# Does Git delete empty folders?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I've committed and pushed a project to my GitHub account.

This project contained the following partial file structure:

```
server 
|
--- conf
|
----- some files 
|
--- java
|
--- lib
```

The java and lib folders are empty.
When downloading my project from GitHub, the resulting zip did not contain the java and lib folders.

Does Git delete empty folders?
I am using Atlassian's SourceTree as my Git client.

Comment: @Idan Adar -- just an FYI, regarding the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worklight-adapters tag, I've had to go through a number of your previous tag wiki suggestions and add sources for heavily plagiarized text.  Per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256436/how-to-deal-with-plagiarized-content-in-tag-wikis?lq=1 and numerous other Meta links, tag wikis need to have a source attribution if heavily copy-and-pasted.  See http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6357996 for a good example.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables  No problem. I'll add a link to our website... It's hardly plagiarized. :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, source added.

Comment: Great Idan... good luck.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Git doesn't delete empty folders; Git cannot *track* empty folders (or any kind of folder) in the first place. Git only tracks files, the folders are incidental. Git only creates folders on disk in order to house files; a folder with no files in it does not exist in Git's world-view.

If you want to keep an "empty" folder in your Git repository, the convention is to add a hidden empty file to that directory, such as `/java/.gitkeep`

Comment: Exactly, Git is a content tracker. Hence, directories aren't indexed by it.